# AVAudioRecorder & AVAudioPlayer with iOS 7 not working properly

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioplayer, ios7, avaudiorecorder, xcode5

i'm having some issue with AVFoundation framework.
I wrote a demo app to record audio, play it, and calculate decibels, with iOS 6.
It both worked with iOS simulator built-in xcode 4.6.3 and my iPhone with iOS 6.1.3

Now i've update xcode to version 5 and tested the appa again. With the built-in simulator it works (both with iOS 6.1 and iOS 7 simulators). But when i deploy the app to my iPhone, with iOS 7.0, it doesn't work anymore.

I'm using `AVAudioRecorder` and `AVAudioPlayer`.

I don't know what could be the problem. Any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: that's exactly what's been happening to me. All my apps that used to work on iOS 6 have just flat out stopped working in iOS 7 for AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer. In my case they don't even work on simulator

Comment: Sam, was your app unable to play audio as well?  Check my answer for the way I figured out how to fix recording, but my playback was still working prior to the fix.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I was having the same issue... It appears as if Apple is now requiring the use of `AVAudioSession` prior to using the `AVAudioRecorder`.  I couldn't find any documentation on this change in requirement, however the recording portion of my app is now working.

All I did was create an `audioSession`, set the category, and set it to be active.  I did this prior to calling `prepareToRecord` and I tried it after the call to `prepareToRecord...` both ways worked.

I hope this fixes your problem!

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: I tried this on my code but its still not working.  Do I need to ask permission to use the microphone first? thanks.

Comment: @atbebtg you might need to replace the category with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`.

Comment: These helped me solve problem. Thanks a lot. Should add a bit of salt. Last two methods have return value. It is not a good practice ignoring return value. It is not acceptable even in example snippets.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue.

I have fixed it by using AVAudioSession. Moreover set properly the category of `AVAudioSession`:

when recording use:

```
[self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
```

when playing use:

`[self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];`

If i don't switch the category when i play, the registration the volume is very low.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this problem so
First I had to make sure the app had permission to use the mic by going to settings -> privacy -> microphone 
then I got success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not have access to the microphone. Use this code:

```
if ([audioSession respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]) {
    [audioSession performSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:) withObject:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            // Microphone enabled code
        }
        else {
            // Microphone disabled code
        }
    }];
}
```